# how to over come ssl certifcate error for selenium web driver in Internet Explorer

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, ssl-certificate

I am new to Selenium Web driver and using this with Java.

I am able to launch an application but I am getting the SSL certificate error, could anyone please let me know how to overcome this issue. 
I am actually learning it and need to implement at my work, if I could overcome this will be very helpful.

I am using the following code :
public class Test1 {

```
private static InternetExplorerDriver driver;

@Before
public void beforeclass ()
{
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\My Folder\\selenium-2.33.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
        capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true); 
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
        capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);

}

@Test
public void Test() throws Exception
{

     driver.get("www.gmail.com");
     driver.getTitle();
     driver.getCurrentUrl();
     System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
             driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("Admin1");
     driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("Password2");
     }

   @After
   public void afterclass()
   {

       System.out.println("webdriver");

   }
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I dont' think there is a way to properly set it. `CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS` won't work for IE I suppose, Selenium is designed to ignore the invalid capability for the particular browser and won't throw an exception.

Here is a workaround you can click link "Continue to this website (not recommended)." to bypass it.

Try

```
// check if your driver is IEDriver and driver's Title contains "Certificate"
// then 
driver.navigate().to("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click()");
driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("Admin1");
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("Password2");
```

Comment: this will get the job done but it will timeout once you have clicked on the override link. It won't know that you changed page (or it will be waiting for the next page) if you are working with POM. At least that's what happens in c#

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same issue i solved it adding target ssl certificates to IE trusted certificates on machine where test executes.
This solved in local dev machine and also on grid execution.(Certificates imported there)

This precentes certificate revogation warning to display on IE.

Answer (score -3):

I did solve this issue by making changes in the settings.Try 
Tools-> Internet options->Advanced-> Settings->under security  uncheck " Warn if changing between secure and not secure mode"
and Restart your IE.

Comment: One big reason this is being downvoted is that this would make all IE activity insecure, not just Selenium.